# What's happening under the hood of an enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, foreach

I wrote the following test when exploring Java's enhanced for loop:

```
class test
{
    int number = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new test();
    }

    public test() {

        int[] numbers = getNumbers();

        for(int number : numbers) {
            System.out.println("number    : " + number);
            System.out.println("numbers[0]: " + numbers[0]);

            numbers = getNumbers();
        }
    }

    public int[] getNumbers() {

        number++;

        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            numbers[i] = number;

        return numbers;
    }
}
```

I was surprised to find my test ouputted:

```
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 1
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 2
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 3
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 4
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 5
```

It appears then that a separate instance of `numbers` is created when the loop is first executed, and is made immutable. From there, any changes made to `numbers` are only made to the version which exists outside the loop condition.

I've confirmed the behavior is at least similar to this by replacing the loop with:

```
for(int number : numbers) {
    System.out.println("number    : " + number);
    numbers = null;
}
```

which gave:

```
number    : 1
number    : 1
number    : 1
number    : 1
number    : 1
```

My question is: what behavior is being hidden from us here? Is a second version of `numbers` copied? Is it actually immutable, or have I not poked it hard enough? In other words:

**What's happening under the hood of an enhanced for loop?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The enhanced `for` loop is covered by the [JLS, Section 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

- For `Iterable` objects:

> The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

- For arrays:

> The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of the form:
>
> ```
> T[] #a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```

It creates a new reference to the array, separate from your original reference.  You can modify the reference to the array all you want, but it will still keep iterating over this implicit reference to the original array.

Over `Iterable`s, only the reference to the `Iterator` is kept, which still refers back to the original `Iterable` object, even if you reassign the original variable during the loop.

Whether you use an enhanced `for` loop over an array or an `Iterable`, you can reassign the reference used as the target without affecting the result of the iteration -- you will still iterate over the original object referred by the target reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the line of your enhanced for loop as so:

```
    for(int number : numbers) {
```

whatever expression that is after the `:` is only evaluated *once*: when the for loop starts. Even though you set a different value to the `numbers` variable while the loop is running, Java has already cached the original value of `numbers` and is iterating over that value. If you print the values in `numbers` after the loop, you will see that `numbers` did change, but the actual array that the for loop was iterating over did not.

```
...
public test() {

    int[] numbers = getNumbers();

    System.out.println("Array before loop starts:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers) + "\n");

    for (int number : numbers) {
        System.out.println("number    : " + number);
        System.out.println("numbers[0]: " + numbers[0]);

        numbers = getNumbers();
    }

    System.out.println("\nArray after loop finishes:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

}
...
```

The above prints:

```
Array before loop starts:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

number    : 1
numbers[0]: 1
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 2
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 3
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 4
number    : 1
numbers[0]: 5

Array after loop finishes:
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of the form:
>
> ```
> T[] #a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```

Observe that `Expression` is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

From the java docs

"For example, this code:

```
List<? extends Integer> l = ...
for (float i : l) ...
```

will be translated to:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> #i = l.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    float #i0 = (Integer)#i.next();
    ...
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

So yes your observation is correct!

Comment: The question was about arrays.

Comment: to which the same applies, no?

Comment: Roughly speaking. There isn't actually an iterator.

Answer (score -1):

> It appears then that a separate instance of numbers is created...

Well... yes. You created five new instances by running `new int[5]` 6 times. And the for loop keeps using the first one. The first one doesn't get garbage collected until the for loop ends, even if you cannot reference it anymore.

It's not recommended to change the collection while looping through it.

Comment: The only correct part was *the for loop keeps using the first one*. Everything else was irrelevant or misleading.